# Testing numeric user input against array elements

Tags: arrays, perl, input

I'm making a simple fortune teller program for a class. I wanted to start by having the user choose between four numbers, like on a paper fortune teller (cootie catcher, as it were).

I created an array, @number_choices = ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ); and I wanted to make sure the user input was equal to one of the numbers in the array. Here is what I have so far, which is not working at all (when I run the program, it prints the error message no matter what number I enter, except for sometimes 2 or 1):

```
    my $number_chosen = <STDIN>;  
    chomp ($number_chosen);  

    my $num;  
    my $found = 0;  

    while ( $found == 0 )   
    {  
         foreach $num (@number_choices)  
         {  
              if ($number_chosen == $num)  
              {  
                    $found = 1;  
                    last;  
               }  

              else  
              {  
                    print "I'm sorry, that number is not valid. Please pick a number: " . join(', ', @number_choices) . "\n";  
                    $number_chosen = <STDIN>;  
                    chomp ($number_chosen);  
               }  
          }  
     }
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error. You choose a number but for every loop through the array it makes you choose another one, so if in the second loop you enter number `2` it will be right regardless of your first input, and same number `3` for third loop.

You should put the error message out of the `foreach` loop and ask for a number inside the `while`. Besides that, the `last` only goes out of the nearest loop, so you need to use a label to go out of the `while`. Something similar to following dirty solution:

```
my @number_choices = (1, 2, 3, 4); 

my $num;  
my $found = 0;  

LOOP:
while ( $found == 0 )   
{   
    $number_chosen = <STDIN>;  
    chomp ($number_chosen);  
     foreach $num (@number_choices)  
     {   
          if ($number_chosen == $num)  
          {   
                $found = 1;  
                last LOOP;
           }   

      }   
      print "I'm sorry, that number is not valid. Please pick a number: " . join(', ', @number_choices) . "\n";  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Birei, I was having trouble wrapping my head around the logic. I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested.